# Adding contentEditable items together with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Update: Put in more context.

Update 2: The sum isn't adding correctly now, and the initial sum doesn't appear until I edit one of the values.

---

I am trying to add contentEditable items from a table in JavaScript.

The three rows I'd like to add are named "string1", "string2", and "string3", and "total" is the id of the row that displays the sum of all three strings.

I attempted to use parseInt to add the numerical values of the numbers already in the table, but the total sum is incorrect for some reason. Also, the the sum of the initial set of numbers is blank until I one of the values. How do I get it to appear when I open the file?

Below is the code:

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First:</td>
      <td id="string1" oninput="myFunction()">100</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>Second:</td>
      <td id="string2" oninput="myFunction()">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third:</td>
      <td id="string3" oninput="myFunction()">100</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td id="total"></td>
    </tr> 
  </table>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("string1").contentEditable = true;
    document.getElementById("string2").contentEditable = true;
    document.getElementById("string3").contentEditable = true;

    var integer1 = document.getElementById("string1").innerText;
    var integer2 = document.getElementById("string2").innerText;
    var integer3 = document.getElementById("string3").innerText;

    var sum = parseInt(integer1) + parseInt(integer2) + parseInt(integer3);

    function myFunction()  {
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
    }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its here:

```
function myFunction()  {
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

Thats an declaration of an function, you just declare it.

You also need to execute that function to make it work with:

```
myFunction()
```

Your code looks like this then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("string1").contentEditable = true;
    document.getElementById("string2").contentEditable = true;
    document.getElementById("string3").contentEditable = true;
    function myFunction()  {
      var integer1 = document.getElementById("string1").innerText;
      var integer2 = document.getElementById("string2").innerText;
      var integer3 = document.getElementById("string3").innerText;

      var sum = parseInt(integer1) + parseInt(integer2) + parseInt(integer3);
    }
    myFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I changed .value to .innerHTML and the numbers added, but the addition is off. Also, the initial sum (400) doesn't appear until after I edit one of the values. How can I get it to appear in the beginning?

Comment: @ttoshiro i have updated my answer, copy paste it and try it out

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `myFunction()` so that code never gets executed.

To make it calculate whatever is in the elements `string1`, `string2`, `string3` you need to listen for a change and then calculate the sum:

```
document.getElementById("string1").contentEditable = true;
document.getElementById("string2").contentEditable = true;
document.getElementById("string3").contentEditable = true;

function myFunction()  {
  // Table cells do not have .value property so we use .innerText
  var integer1 = document.getElementById("string1").innerText;
  var integer2 = document.getElementById("string2").innerText;
  var integer3 = document.getElementById("string3").innerText;

  var sum = parseInt(integer1, 10) + parseInt(integer2, 10) + parseInt(integer3, 10);

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = isNaN(sum) ? 0 : sum;
}

document.getElementById("string1").addEventListener("input", myFunction);
document.getElementById("string2").addEventListener("input", myFunction);
document.getElementById("string3").addEventListener("input", myFunction);

// do initial calculation
myFunction();
```

Also you should always pass the second parameter (`radix`) of `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did this but I am still receiving an "NaN" and the initial sum (400) doesn't appear when I open the script. I also added more context to my post